# PayPal IPN - what to do if details are wrong?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

At the end of the IPN docs it says the following:

```
Important: After you have authenticated an IPN message (that is, received a VERIFIED response from PayPal), you must perform these important checks before you can assume that the IPN is both legitimate and has not already been processed:
1.Check that the payment_status is Completed.
2.If the payment_status is Completed, check the txn_id against the previous PayPal transaction that you processed to ensure the IPN message is not a duplicate.
3.Check that the receiver_email is an email address registered in your PayPal account.
4.Check that the price (carried in mc_gross) and the currency (carried in mc_currency) are correct for the item (carried in item_name or item_number).
```

What are you supposed to do if one of these checks fails? Are we supposed to call a PayPal API somehow to 'reject' the transaction'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most shops would mark an order / transaction that fails these checks as "Possible Fraud" or something along these lines. 
The order status should raise awareness with the employee working the orders - a closer look should show which check has failed and further actions can be initiated.

This may range from refunding the transactions to contacting PayPal for possible fraud attempts. In any case, the order should be checked and not just treated as any other "Completed" order.

---

Sample scenario:

- You're using unencrypted Website Payments Standard, HTML Forms to receive payments.
- A fraudulent buyer finds out and starts modifying the price of an item through editing the submitted form
- You receive the order as PAID and don't check the value of the order within your shop against the transaction
- An employee doesn't spot this and an item worth 200$ is sent out for a payment of 0.01$

---

Comment: Thanks - so the short answer is "refund the transactions or contact PayPal for possible fraud attempts". Is there any guideline as to when and how we should contact PayPal? e.g. if its more than x times per day ?